# Verify the visibility of a specific list element - Katalon

Tags: selenium-webdriver, katalon-studio

I have the following method that takes an integer input and clicks on the item from a list.

```
def static selectItem(int itemIndex) {
    WebUI.waitForElementVisible(findTestObject('dashboard/ItemList'), 7, FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE);

    final List<TestObject> items =
            CommonUtils.findVisibleElementsFromTestObject(findTestObject('dashboard/ItemList'));

    WebUI.click(items.get(itemIndex));
}
```

In my test class, I am loading the dashboard page and before clicking a particular item, I want to make sure that it is visible on the screen.

For example,

Dashboard.selectItem(17) should click the 16th item on the list. I know one way is to verify the visibility of the complete list but I am looking for a way to verify visibility of a specific item (16th in my case) from a list.

Answer (score 0):

`WebUI.waitForElementVisible()` [method](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/webui-wait-for-element-visible.html#description) returns

> true: the element is present and visible within the timeout

and

> false: the element is NOT present and visible within the timeout

So, you could create a new method that would look something like this

```
def static isItemVisible(int itemIndex, int timeout) {

    final List<TestObject> items =
            CommonUtils.findVisibleElementsFromTestObject(findTestObject('dashboard/ItemList'));

    WebUI.waitForElementVisible(findTestObject('dashboard/ItemList'), timeout, FailureHandling.OPTIONAL);

}
```

Failure handling has been changed to "OPTIONAL" so the test won't fail in case the element is not found.